# C Ignoring some lines, and then print the rest of the lines

Tags: c, file, line

I am trying to make a program to read some data from a `.dat` file, and just print it to my console

the `.dat` file looks like:

```
# Channel A: 
# Channel A: 
# Channel B: 
# Channel B: 
# time_in_sec channelA_value channelB_value
1377505127.976349  
1377505128.976567 GW.Inc,GDM-8246,FW1.00 
1377505129.476435 DCA 
1377505129.976502 -00000. 
1377505130.476462 -00000. 
1377505130.976538 -00000. 
1377505131.476524 -00000. 
1377505131.976527 -00000. 
1377505132.476526 -00000.
```

I want to read and print the lines after `DCA` 
but I don't know how to start read/print after that line.

Comment: Parsing is not the strongest side of C. I suggest to use other tools (sed, grep etc.) for that and pass assorted data to your program to avoid many headaches, unless you absolutely must stick to plain C.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no own effort.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can follow the hints below:

1. read lines one by one using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).
2. check for the presence of the substring `"DCA"` using [`strstr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr).

Then,

- if found, continue `fgets()` and from next iteration, use `printf()` to print the output.
- if not found, continue to `fgets()`.

<sup>Note: while using `fgets()`, you need to take care of the possible `\n` at the end yourself.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do it using C? If you just want `Ignoring some lines, and then print the rest of the lines`, try other tools that can do this job in a more convenient way. With `sed`:

```
sed -nre '/^.*DCA *$/,$ {/^.*DCA *$/!p}' yourfile
```

If you do want to write it in C, well, leave this answer alone.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
char buf[1000];
/* skip lines until DCA */
while( fgets(buf, 1000, f) && strcmp( buf + strlen(buf) - 5, " DCA\n" ) );
/* print all the rest */
while( fgets(buf, 1000, f) )
   fputs(buf, stdout);
```

If program should handle Windows/Mac style line ends adjustments would be necessary. Also if whitespaces after "DCA" are allowed.

If more complex handling is required I would use regular expressions (see `regexec()`).